# Poor write Performance by HBase client

Tags: performance, hadoop, hbase, scalability

I'm using HBase client in my application server (-cum web-server) with HBase
cluster setup of 6 nodes using CDH3u4 (HBase-0.90). HBase/Hadoop services
running on cluster are:

```
NODENAME-- ROLE

Node1 -- NameNode
Node2 -- RegionServer, SecondaryNameNode, DataNode, Master
Node3 -- RegionServer, DataNode, Zookeeper
Node4 -- RegionServer, DataNode, Zookeeper
Node5 -- RegionServer, DataNode, Zookeeper
Node6 -- Cloudera Manager, RegionServer, DataNode
```

I'm using following optimizations for my HBase client:

1. auto-flush = false
2. ClearbufferOnFail=true
3. HTable bufferSize = 12MB
4. Put setWriteToWAL = false (I'm fine with loss of 1 data).

In order to be closely consistent between read and write, I'm calling
flush-commits on all the buffered tables at every 2 sec.

In my application, I place the HBase write call in a Queue (async manner) and
draining the queue using 20 Consumer threads. On hitting web-server locally
using curl, I'm able to see TPS of 2500 for HBase after curl completes, but
with Load-test where request is coming at high rate of 1200 hits per second
on 3 application servers,the Consumer(drain) threads which are responsible to
write to HBase are not writing data at a rate comparable to input rate. I'm
seeing not more than 600 TPS when request rate is 1200 hits per second.

Can anyone suggest what we can do to improve performance? I've tried with
reduced threads to 7 on each of 3 app server but still no effect. An expert
opinion would be helpful. As this is a production server, so not thinking
to swap the roles, unless someone point severe performance benefit.

[EDIT]:
Just to highlight/clarify our HBase writing pattern, our 1st Transaction checks the row in Table-A (using HTable.exists). It fails to find the row first time and so write to three tables. Subsequent 4 Transaction make exist check on Table-A and as it finds the row, it writes only to 1 Table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that's a pretty ancient version of HBase.  **As of Aug 18, 2013, I would recommend upgrading to something based off of 0.94.x.**

Other than that it's really hard to tell you for sure.  There are lots of tuning knobs.  You should :

- Make sure that HDFS has enough xceivers.
- Make sure that HBase has enough heap space.
- Make sure there is no swapping
- Make sure there are enough handlers.
- Make sure that you have compression turned on. [1]
- Check disk io
- Make sure that your row keys, column family names, column qualifiers, and values are as small as possible
- Make sure that your writes are well distributed across your key space'
- Make sure your regions are (pre-)split
- If you're on a recent version then you might want to look at encoding [2]

After all of those things are taken care of then you can start looking at logs and jstacks.

1. https://hbase.apache.org/book/compression.html
2. https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/encoding/FastDiffDeltaEncoder.html

Comment: Thanks for the insight eclark. We got some of the same feedback(pre-splits, handlers) from Definitive guide and so have incorporated those. Yet to test their effectiveness under-load.  Yet, would like to understand few points you've highlighted. Compression - you mean Table compression strategy, i.e GZIP, LZO, etc ? And Check Disk IO, this is what HBase is doing to HDFS?

Comment: Compression: Yea I mean Column Family compression LZO/Snappy/LZ4 (stay away from gzip as a rule of thumb).

Check Disk IO: Make sure it's even.  Make sure there isn't too much.  > 90 megabytes per second write won't really work for long.  You'lll have disk queues at some point.